# SQL Server Query with 6M records taking 8 Sec is it Normal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server Query with 6M records taking 8 Sec is it Normal ?

If no then how i can optimize the query to reduce execution time

```
select ChargeID , SUM(Fee) from Charges group by ChargeID
```

The Server Machine is an Xeon(R) CPU with 12GB of RAM and running 64-bit OS
Memory usage is nearly 10GB and CPU ussage is 5-10 %

Charges Table  have only Clustered Index ChargeID.

Here is Execution Plan

[image]

Recommend some tips or tricks that can reduce the execution time Thanks

Comment: We need much more info in order to help you. The execution time depends on several factors: the HW in the server, disk I/O usage, CPU usage, the load of the server, the structure of your table, the indexes, their fragmentation, statistisc etc etc etc. This question is too board to help you. (8 secs **could** be normal).

Comment: Depends perhaps also on whether the table data is cached in memory and how much memory the SQL Server instance is using. Check this http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72271/44324

Comment: And like always - server specs that totally ignore the msot important factor: The disc subsystem.

Comment: did you check the execution plan? you may get some hint about issues & improvements.

Comment: there is nothing to optimize in that SQL, but check the explain plan anyway

Comment: Seems to be a simple straightforward query and 8sec for 6M records is not bad at all. On top of it, you've got aggregate function and an Order By.

Comment: It is bad. Seriously. Or not. Depends on the server. I regularly aggregate 10 times that amount in less seconds - but that is on a more powerfull server. I would assume we run - a problem here with the disc. Latencies would be nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends on the server, likely more the disc IO.

YOu do an index seek - that is as good as it gets. THe question is how fast teh discs deliver the data. I would expect a lot less time, but then I would expect the "discs" to be SSD in 2014 for any real analysis.

I would check disc IO, latencies etc. - but from the SQL side there is nothing you can do anymore, that is as good as it gets as a query plan.

Comment: Thanks TomTom for you time and Answer.